# Conflicting type for a function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

Here is the error message:

> replace2.c:41: warning: conflicting types for ‘replace’ 
>   replace2.c:27: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘replace’ was
>   here

here is my function:

```
   void replace ( int *a1, int *a2, int n)
   {
    int *p;
    int *p2;
    int sum = 0;
    for (p = a1, p2 = a2; p < a1 + n; p++, p2++)
    {
    sum = (6 + *p) % 10;
    *p2 = sum;
    }

 }
```

here is where I called:

please note int_lenght is scanned (input is given by the user), before calling the function.

```
         int int_lenght;
         array[int_lenght];
         arrayb[int_lenght];

         replace(array, arrayb, int_lenght);
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?  Do you have a prototype for the function in scope before you call it?

Comment: Note that the normal spelling of 'length' has the t before the h.

Comment: sorry should have added that:                                                       replace2.c:41: warning: conflicting types for ‘replace’
replace2.c:27: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘replace’ was here

Answer (score 1):

May be the problem is that `replace` was not declared before it is used. Like this,

```
 void replace(int*, int*, int);
```

Comment: almost positive that this is not the problem. I have used them before without declaring them and it works, the first chunk of my code should be a declaration of the function. "i think"

Comment: `I have used them before without declaring them and it works` sure, but have you placed the function above or below its calling statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your replace function is taking 2 pointer value and an integer value but your are sending two array instead of integer

```
int int_lenght;
array[int_lenght];
arrayb[int_lenght];

replace(array[int_lenght], arrayb[int_lenght], int_lenght);
```

Hope it helps you.